# How in Laravel 8 / Blade file not to show errors on variables defined in control?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

In My PhpStorm 2019.2.5 working with Laravel 8 / Blade app I see some variables marked as undefined:

[image]

but actually all variables are defined in the control, not in blade php file...

Is there a way not to show such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
/** @var MyType $myVariable */
?>
your template below...
```

IDEs have no idea how the frameworks work and that's the way to let them understand declared variables

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use <?php in blade files..  ..this will resolve your issue.

Change all of your

```
<?php echo $variable ?>
```

To

```
{{ $variable }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable PHPStorm's inspection of undefined variables by enabling "Search for variable's defination outside the current file"[image]